# User-friendly tool to edit databases in Eclipse

Tags: java, database, eclipse, h2, eclipse-dtp

Is there any tool in Eclipse comparable with phpMyAdmin? The project is in Java and I want to use H2 database. I have installed DTP but it is not as much user-friendly as phpMyAdmin. I did not find the way to create a table without typing sql query.

Answer (score 1):

Check [**Quantum plugin for Eclipse**](http://quantum.sourceforge.net/). Is a friendly interface to manipulate databases.

Another option is [**Eclipse SQL Explorer**](http://www.sqlexplorer.org/screenshots.php).

Answer (score 0):

you can use squirrel or dbvisualizer. both are two software that use the jdbc to connect on a database, and for dbvisualizer should be an eclipse plugin...